# Remove $init$ method from class with subclass

Tags: java, scala, dbus

I am using a Java library in Scala that generates D-Bus interfaces from class definitions. It works fine with a simple Scala class:

```
@DBusInterfaceName("me.TestInterface")
trait TestInterface extends DBusInterface {
  def changeSomething(thing: String): Unit
}
```

I need to add a sub-class in order to implement a D-Bus Signal:

```
@DBusInterfaceName("me.TestInterface")
trait TestInterface extends DBusInterface {
  def changeSomething(thing: String): Unit

  final class SomethingChanged(thing: String) extends DBusSignal("SomethingChanged")
}
```

When I do this I get an extrat method `$init$` on my D-Bus interface, presumably because this is being added by Scala.

Is it possible to generate a class with a sub-class in Scala that does not have this extra `$init$` method?

I can clearly just write this in Java and import it, but I would rather stick to pure Scala.

Comment: Why? What's the issue with?

Comment: Make it a class instead of a trait?

Comment: @cchantep The `$init$` method becomes part of the published D-Bus interface even though it is not one of my interface methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I realised that Java uses a `static class` as the inner class. The equivalent in Scala is to put the class in the companion object:

```
@DBusInterfaceName("me.TestInterface")
trait TestInterface extends DBusInterface {
  def changeSomething(thing: String): Unit
}

object TestInterface {
  case class SomethingChanged(thing: String) extends DBusSignal("/me/Test")
}
```

This does work in Scala 2.13, but I am not sure whether this is behaviour that I can rely on or just a feature of the current implementation.